# Proof that stochastic discount factor is positive in complete markets

Tags: finance, intertemporal-choice

I am looking for a reference (with a proof possibly) to understand why the completeness of markets implies that the stochastic discount factor is strictly positive in the context of intertemporal consumption, i.e. when a agent FOC implies

$$
p_t = \mathbb{E}\left[\beta \frac{u'(c_{t+1})}{u'(c_t)} x_{t+1}\right]
$$

where $p_t$ is the price of an asset giving $x_{t+1}$ in the following period.

Answer (score 5):

> ...the completeness of markets implies that the stochastic discount
> factor is strictly positive...

This statement is not quite correct.
Rather, the agent's optimality condition implies that market is complete with respect to the agent's consumption-relevant states, and that the SDF must be strictly positive on those states.

The SDF is, more or less, same as Arrow-Debreu prices on consumption-relevant states, which must be strictly positive. Otherwise equilibrium would not exist. Marginal utility cannot be zero in equilibrium.
(SDF is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of AD prices with respect to the physical measure. SDF is strictly positive if and only if AD prices are.)

For simplicity, assume agent's consumption is $\omega$-contingent, where $\omega$ belongs to a finite set $\Omega$.
Then the FOC
$$
p_t = \mathbb{E}\left[\beta \frac{u'(c_{t+1})}{u'(c_t)} x_{t+1}\right]
$$
becomes
$$
p_t = \sum_{\omega \in \Omega}  \beta \frac{u'(c_{t+1}(\omega))}{u'(c_t (\omega))} \cdot x_{t+1} (\omega) \cdot P(\omega).
$$
The quantity
$$
\beta \frac{u'(c_{t+1}(\omega))}{u'(c_t (\omega))} \cdot P(\omega)
$$
can be viewed as the price of a claim with payoff $1_{\{ \omega' =\omega\}}(\omega')$ (i.e. a digital option that pays 1 if $\omega$ realizes and 0 otherwise).
Such claims are exactly the Arrow-Debreu securities in the market of $\omega$-contingent claims.

(If the payoff $x_{t+1}$ is contingent on, say, state $(\omega, \nu)$, where agent's consumption is invariant with respect to $\nu$, then market is complete only with respect to $\omega$-contingent claims.
Claims whose payoffs depend on $\nu$ cannot be replicated, i.e. market is not complete with respect to such claims.
In the FOC, the $\nu$-coordinate would be integrated out.)

In equilibrium, the FOC becomes the asset pricing equation
$$
p_t = \mathbb{E}\left[\beta \frac{u'(c_{t+1})}{u'(c_t)} p_{t+1}\right].
$$
This means, in the market of AD securities of $\omega$-contingent claims, the (representative) agent holds the portfolio that is the asset itself.